# Taking Values From a Dropdown and Putting them into a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a web application for my capstone course and am having an issue with inserting data into my table from a drop down. We are able to populate it but when trying to post it into the table we aren't seeing it show up. The table we are trying to insert it into is an associative table and we are trying to insert QMID, Category, and Questions in it. I'm guessing it can't show a row if all three fields are not inserted at the same time. My code for the form is:

```
<?php
require_once('php/CreateQuizSQL.php'); 
require_once('php/Connection.php');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Create a Quiz</title>
<link href="css/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery.ui.button.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/capm styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="css/jQueryAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/jQueryAssets/jquery.ui-1.10.4.datepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="ui-widget" style="background:linear-gradient(white, white, white, white, #fece2f, #e78f08); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-attachment:fixed">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none">
                <li><a class="active" href="php/logoff.php">Log Out</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Quizzes</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Course Quizzes</a>
            <a href="PracticeExamStart.php">Practice Exam</a>
            <a href="CreateAQuiz.php">Design A Quiz</a>
        </div></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="Profile.php" class="dropbtn">Profile</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="Profile.php">My Dashboard</a>
            <a href="Settings.php">Settings</a>
            <a href="Contacts.php">Contacts</a>
        </div></li>
        <li><a href="MainPage.php">Home</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Admin</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="AdminViewGrades.php">View Grades</a>
            <a href="AdminReports.php">Build Reports</a>
            <a href="AdminQuestions.php">Add/Edit Questions</a>
            <a href="AdminCreateQuiz.php">Create A Quiz</a>
            <a href="AdminUsers.php">Add/Edit Users</a>
        </div></li>
    </ul>
<header>
        <a href="MainPage.php"><img src="images/THE ONE.png" width="341" height="136" alt=""/></a>
</header>
<section>
<div align="center"><a href="#addq">Create Quiz</a> &#8226 <a href="#uploadq">Assign Quiz</a> &#8226 <a href="#editdeleteq">Edit Quiz</a> &#8226</div>
<form method="POST"  action= "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">


<h4 id="addq" >Quiz Requirements</h4>


</p>
<p>
  <label>

    Number of Attempts: <input type="text" placeholder="Attempts" name="attempts" size="4"></label>
  <br><br>
  <label>
    Time Limit: <input type="text" placeholder="Time Limit" name="timelimit" size="6"></label>
  <br><br>


  <label>Due Date: <input type="text" placeholder ="Date" name="date" size="10"></label>


<br><br>
 </p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

  </form>

  <form method="POST"  action= "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">

  <h4 id="addq" >Select Category</h4>
  <p>Quiz Master ID: </p>
    <select name= "qmid">
        <?php
            $sql= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT QMID FROM QuizMaster");
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<option value=\"{$row['QMID']}\">" . $row['QMID'] .       "</option>";
                }
                ?>
    </select>
  <!--<?php if (!empty($dollarsign)) {echo("<b>$dollarsign</b>");}?></p>-->


<p>Category:</p>
<select name="category">
    <?php 
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT Category FROM Category");
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<option value=\"{$row['Category']}\">" . $row['Category'] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>


</select> 

<p><label>Number of Questions: <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" name="questions" size="4"></label>
<p>If you want to add another category, click yes below.</p>

<!--<button id="Button2" type="Submit">Yes</button>--!>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
 <?php
$result = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT QMID FROM QuizMaster ORDER BY QMID DESC LIMIT 1;');
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   $max_QMID=$result-> fetch_assoc();
   echo $max_QMID['QMID']; //Here it is
}
?>
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

and then the code for the processes inside that form is:

```
<?php
    include('Connection.php');// Connects us to the database
    $error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors
//Check to see if the post was to itself.
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=== 'POST') {
    //If any of the textboxes are empty, then show the error.
    if(empty($_POST["attempts"]) || empty($_POST["timelimit"]) || empty ($_POST["date"]))
    {
            $error = "Please fill in all blanks.";
            }
    else{

/*if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   $max_QMID=$result-> fetch_assoc();*/
        $attempts= ($_POST['attempts']);
        $timelimit= ($_POST['timelimit']);
        $date= ($_POST['date']);
        if(isset($_POST['questions'])){
        $questions= ($_POST['questions']);}
        if(isset($_POST['category'])){
        $category= ($_POST['category']);}
        if(isset($_POST['qmid'])){
        $QMID= ($_POST['qmid']);}


        $prepared_statement =$connect->prepare( 'INSERT INTO QuizMaster (DueDate, AttemptsMax, Time) VALUES (?,?, ?)');
        $prepared_statement->bind_param("sss", $_POST["date"], $_POST["attempts"], $_POST["timelimit"]);
        $prepared_statement->execute();
        $prepared_statement->close();






      // $dollarsign= $max_QMID['QMID']; //Here it is 

 // }

}
if(empty($_POST["attempts"]) && empty($_POST["timelimit"]) && empty ($_POST["date"]))
    {
               $prepared_statement=$connect->prepare('INSERT INTO Qmcategory (Quantity, Category, QMID) VALUES (?,?,?)');
        $prepared_statement->bind_param("sss", $questions, ".$_POST['category'].", ".$_POST[qmid].");
        $prepared_statement->execute();
        $prepared_statement->close();
            }

}








?>
```

Comment: The .min.css and .css contain the same stuff - the only difference is that the .min.css file is **minimized**.  You only need one of the two - I suggest the **.min.css** versions.  This is only a comment because it is unrelated to your question, but worth addressing.

Comment: Thanks! I'll change that!